# Several template locations for Thymeleaf in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Currently `Spring Boot` allow one value for the `Thymeleaf` templates location with the `spring.thymeleaf.prefix` property.

> The default value is `classpath:/templates/`.

I want to have another location for the thymeleaf templates (but keep the default one), outside the jar, for example:

> `spring.thymeleaf.prefix = classpath:/templates/, file:/resources/templates`

Do i have to define another template resolver for the new location i want ?

Comment: I have to put a `ITemplateResolver` bean with the wanted prefix value. The resolver should be ordered before the Spring resolver (with `HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` for example) and should be have the `checkExistence` flag.

Comment: Hope my answer solves your requirement

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define the setting in the `application.properties` file

```
spring.thymeleaf.templateResolverOrder=1
```

Now in your custom Bean which creates ITemplateResolver set order to 0 along with prefix and suffix. This way spring boot will listen to both places

Setting order to 0 is important

An example of bean creation can be

```
@Bean
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver emailTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    emailTemplateResolver.setPrefix("mails/");
    emailTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    emailTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    emailTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    emailTemplateResolver.setOrder(0);
    emailTemplateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);

    return emailTemplateResolver;
}
```

[MyExample](https://github.com/rajadileepkolli/springsecuredthymeleafapp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/learning/securedapp/configuration/ThymeleafConfigurator.java#L17-L27)

Comment: Perfect! I'd like to highlight the importance of the line `emailTemplateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);`. Without it, if a template is not found by that resolver, it won't continue searching in the rest.

Answer (score 3):

In order to define multiple template locations, you must define Spring beans implementing ITemplateResolver.

```
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver firstTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/templatelocation/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setOrder(0);
    templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);

    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver secondTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/templatelocation/other/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setOrder(1);
    templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);

    return templateResolver;
}
```

You can also check out the [blog post](http://www.javabyexamples.com/thymeleaf-multiple-template-locations-using-spring-boot/) detailing the usage.