# Spring Boot cannot change Thymeleaf template directory with Java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Placing Thymeleaf template files in the default `src/main/resources/templates` works OK for me. When I want to rename the directory say to `mytemplates`; it does not work.

I receive *Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)* warning when 
the application starts.

When I point to the home page, I get *org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers* error.

I use the following Java configuration:

```
package com.zetcode.conf;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Description;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5")
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {

        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver tres = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

        tres.setPrefix("classpath:/mytemplates/");
        tres.setSuffix(".html");        
        tres.setCacheable(false);
        tres.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        tres.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return tres;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {

        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf view resolver")
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setCache(false);
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);

        return viewResolver;
    }    

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following :

1st: define the below setting in the `application.properties` file

```
spring.thymeleaf.templateResolverOrder=1
```

Now customize your implementation.

```
@Bean
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver yourTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver yourTemplateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    yourTemplateResolver.setPrefix("yourTemplates/");
    yourTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    yourTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    yourTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    yourTemplateResolver.setOrder(0);  // this is iportant. This way spring 
                                       //boot will listen to both places 0 
                                       //and 1
    emailTemplateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);

    return yourTemplateResolver;
}
```

Source: [Several template locations for Thymeleaf in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42693692/several-template-locations-for-thymeleaf-in-spring-boot)

Comment: It gave my some hints why it might not work. But I could not get it working; Spring Boot keeps giving the same error message. (There is no setCheckExistence() method.)

Answer (score 5):

By default, thymeleaf templates are read from **src/main/resources/templates** folder. [Chandu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3086800/chandu) has given a solution for custom template location name.

You first add a application.properties file in your class path and put all the following properties **src/main/resources/application.properties** in this file.

```
spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true # Check that the template exists before rendering it.
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true # Check that the templates location exists.
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true # Enable MVC Thymeleaf view resolution.
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/ # Prefix that gets prepended to view names when building a URL.
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html # Suffix that gets appended to view names when building a URL.
```

Resource Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41319170/2293534

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I have figured out:

```
ClassLoaderTemplateResolver tres = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
tres.setPrefix("mytemplates/");
```

There should be no `classpath:` prefix when using `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver`.

The template directories must not be empty. The Java config takes precedence over the properties configuration. (Using order does not seem to affect  this.)

Answer (score 1):

Following configuration (Spring Boot 2.5.4), where I am instantiating the `FileTemplateResolver` is working the best for me.

In kotlin:

```
@Configuration
class ThymeleafConfig {

   @Value("\${spring.thymeleaf.prefix}")
   private val mailTemplatesPath: String? = null

   @Bean
   fun thymeleafTemplateEngineWithFileResolver(templateResolver: 
                    ITemplateResolver?): SpringTemplateEngine? {
    val templateEngine = SpringTemplateEngine()
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(thymeleafFileTemplateResolver())
    return templateEngine
   }

   fun thymeleafFileTemplateResolver(): ITemplateResolver {
       val templateResolver = FileTemplateResolver()
       templateResolver.prefix = mailTemplatesPath
       templateResolver.suffix = ".html"
       templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML")
       templateResolver.characterEncoding = "UTF-8"
       templateResolver.isCacheable = false
       return templateResolver
   }

}
```

Then the property `spring.thymeleaf.prefix` can be set to any directory e.g.

```
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    prefix: /home/foo/
```

You can also set this property from outside while running your JAR.

Answer (score 0):

It have to do with the order that Spring initiate the template resolver. You will have to do it post-construct, or your custom template resolver might be overwritten by Spring.
I was unsuccessful in sorting this out by setting the order of the template resolvers.

```
    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        return new SpringTemplateEngine();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @Description("Executing @PostContruct since otherwise Spring will overwrite setting with 'SpringTemplateResolver'")
    fun initTemplateResolver() {
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver())
    }
```