# Thymeleaf TemplateInputException when loading html page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a html page where I use jQuery to load page content from a spring boot application

here is the project structure

[image: structure of my project]

I m using zuul as proxy I m confident about the Zuul Eureka configuration on my project

When I try to access my root project page (facturation.html) by calling in browser for localhost:9999/facturation I'm getting the following exception

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "root folder where all thymeleaf files/facturation.html")

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ClassLoader resource "root folder where all thymeleaf files/facturation.html" could not be resolved
> at org.thymeleaf.templateresource.ClassLoaderTemplateResource.reader(ClassLoaderTemplateResource.java:130) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:223) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: ClassLoader resource "root folder where all thymeleaf files/facturation.html" could not be resolved

My spring controller is as below

```
    @Controller
    public class LandingController {
    
        
        private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LandingController.class);
    
        
    
        
        
        @Autowired
        private AppClientFeign appClientFeign;
        
        @Autowired
        private UserClientFeign userClientFeign;
    
    
        @RequestMapping("/")
        String home(Model model,Principal principal) {
            List<Menu> appMenus = appClientFeign.getAppMenus("facturation");
            model.addAttribute("applications", appClientFeign.getApps());
            model.addAttribute("applicationsHistory", appClientFeign.getAppsHistory(principal.getName()));
            model.addAttribute("currentUser", userClientFeign.getUserDetails(principal.getName()));
            if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                StringBuilder stringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder2.append(appMenus);
                stringBuilder2.append("");
                log.debug(stringBuilder2.toString());
            }
            model.addAttribute("menuV", appMenus);
            model.addAttribute("addClientObject", AddClientDTO.builder().build());
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append(" hello world ****************** ---------------------- ************************ \n \n \n");
            stringBuilder.append(appClientFeign.getApps());
            if(log.isDebugEnabled())log.debug(stringBuilder.toString());
            return "facturation";
        }
    @RequestMapping("/html/{page}")
    String resolveHTML(Model model,Principal principal,@PathVariable String page) {
        List<Menu> appMenus = appClientFeign.getAppMenus("facturation");
        model.addAttribute("applications", appClientFeign.getApps());
        model.addAttribute("applicationsHistory", appClientFeign.getAppsHistory(principal.getName()));
        model.addAttribute("currentUser", userClientFeign.getUserDetails(principal.getName()));
        if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder2.append(appMenus);
            stringBuilder2.append("");
            log.debug(stringBuilder2.toString());
        }
        model.addAttribute("menuV", appMenus);
        model.addAttribute("addClientObject", AddClientDTO.builder().build());
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(" hello world ****************** ---------------------- ************************ \n \n \n");
        stringBuilder.append(appClientFeign.getApps());
        if(log.isDebugEnabled())log.debug(stringBuilder.toString());
        return page;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/html/{folder}/{page}")
    String resolveHTML(Model model,Principal principal,@PathVariable String page,@PathVariable String folder) {
        List<Menu> appMenus = appClientFeign.getAppMenus("facturation");
        model.addAttribute("applications", appClientFeign.getApps());
        model.addAttribute("applicationsHistory", appClientFeign.getAppsHistory(principal.getName()));
        model.addAttribute("currentUser", userClientFeign.getUserDetails(principal.getName()));
        if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder2.append(appMenus);
            stringBuilder2.append("");
            log.debug(stringBuilder2.toString());
        }
        model.addAttribute("menuV", appMenus);
        model.addAttribute("addClientObject", AddClientDTO.builder().build());
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(" hello world ****************** ---------------------- ************************ \n \n \n");
        stringBuilder.append(appClientFeign.getApps());
        if(log.isDebugEnabled())log.debug(stringBuilder.toString());
        return folder+"/"+page;
    }
    
}
```

My facturation.htl page is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Facturation - MDS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/js/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/js/facturation.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/js/chart.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/js/menus.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/js/grid.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/js/tab.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/js/notify.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/js/print.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/js/check.js"></script>
    <script onloadstart="loadAdditionalData()" src="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/js/facturationLoader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/css/main.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/css/facturation.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/css/chart.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/css/grid.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/css/tab.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/css/notify.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/css/menus.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/css/dropdown.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:9999/MDS-WEB-RESSOURCE/css/check.css"/>   
</head>

    
<body>

<div id="overlay" class="overlay">
    <div class="form-container">
    </div>
</div>
    
<div style="height: 100%;">
    <div id="header" class="header">
    </div>  
    <div id="menu0" class="menu-V">
    </div>  
    <div class="container">
        <div id="menu0-func0-panel" class="main-panel" style="display: block;">         
        </div>
        <div id="menu0-func1-panel" class="main-panel">
        </div>      
        <div id="menu0-func2-panel" class="main-panel">
        </div>
        <div id="menu0-func3-panel" class="main-panel">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

finally loader.js is as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#header").load("http://"+document.location.host+"/facturation/html/facturation-header");
    $("#menu0").load("http://"+document.location.host+"/facturation/html/facturation-menu0");
    $("#menu0-func0-panel").load("http://"+document.location.host+"/facturation/html/facturation-menu0-func0-panel", function() {
        var option={
            parent: "#stat-container",
            type: "Pie",
            labels: ['FACTURES EN ATTENTE', 'FACTURES EN RETARD (- DE 30 JOURS)', 'FACTURES EN RETARD (+ DE 30 JOURS)'],
            data: [20, 15, 10],
            colors: ["#0ae1ff", "#067180", "#dd4d40"],              
            canvasWidth: 250,
            canvasHeight: 250,
            legendType: "value",
            legendPosition: "bottom", 
            legendUnit: "DZD",
            overlay: false                    
        };
        chart(option);
    });
    $("#menu0-func1-panel").load("http://"+document.location.host+"/facturation/html/facturation-menu0-func1-panel");
    $("#menu0-func2-panel").load("http://"+document.location.host+"/facturation/html/facturation-menu0-func2-panel");
    $("#menu0-func3-panel").load("http://"+document.location.host+"/facturation/html/facturation-menu0-func3-panel");
});
```

to be honest, I don't have the slightest clue why I m getting this, nor an idea about what should I do or try.

NB: I m using zuul and eureka as mentioned, my service is named facturation that why I'm adding facturation after zuul address so he knows which service to contact

Comment: before I did have only one big html called facturation.html and every thing was working fine

Comment: Why are you adding `/facturation`, before `/html`, do you have multiple applications? Which might be weird considering you are using Spring-Boot and you didn't add the `@RequestMapping("/facturation)` to your class. Anyways, you should't use relative paths. Just use `load("/facturacion/html/{page}")`, where page is the desired page.

Comment: @AlainCruz as mentioned I have zuul over eureka where my service name is mapped to facturation (my app name and context_path) this helps zuul to fetch the  service url using a name not an Ip adresse ( wich will be helpfull whel loadbalnacing in the futur)

Comment: When your controller receive your GET request, the page variable is indeed as you expected? Also, could you post your Thymeleaf configuration, if you do have one? Your error message is kind of different than what I would expect. `java.io.FileNotFoundException: ClassLoader resource "root folder where all thymeleaf files/facturation.html" could not be resolved`. As if you were looking into a directory called files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710326/spring-boot-cannot-change-thymeleaf-template-directory-with-java-config) I configured thymeleaf to get my pages from the classpath